# How to use different template for different browser

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like to deliver special versions of my django site for different (mobile-)browser.
What are possible solutions to do this?

Comment: Seems like this has already been answered here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164427/change-django-templates-based-on-user-agent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164427/change-django-templates-based-on-user-agent)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Django Templates Based on User-Agent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164427/change-django-templates-based-on-user-agent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, do smthg like this

```
def map(request, options=None, longitude=None, latitude = None):
    if 'iPhone' in request.META["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]:
        user_agent = 'iPhone'
    elif 'MSIE' in request.META["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]: 
        user_agent ='MSIE'
    else: user_agent=''
    print user_agent
    return render_to_response('map/map.html', 
        {
            'user_agent': user_agent
        })
```

and in your template

```
{% ifnotequal user_agent "iPhone" %}
    {% ifequal user_agent "MSIE" %}
        {% include 'map/map_ie.html' %}
    {% else %}
        {% include 'map/map_default.html' %}
    {% endifequal %}
{% else %}
{% include 'map/map_iphone.html' %}
{% endifnotequal %}
```

Comment: doesn't matter :D Welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

best practice: use [minidetector](http://code.google.com/p/minidetector/) to add the extra info to the request, then use django's built in request context to pass it to your templates like so.

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def my_view_on_mobile_and_desktop(request)
    .....
    render_to_response('regular_template.html', 
                       {'my vars to template':vars}, 
                       context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

then in your template you are able to introduce stuff like:

```
<html>
  <head>
  {% block head %}
    <title>blah</title>
  {% if request.mobile %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/styles/base-mobile.css">
  {% else %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/styles/base-desktop.css">
  {% endif %}
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="navigation">
      {% include "_navigation.html" %}
    </div>
    {% if not request.mobile %}
    <div id="sidebar">
      <p> sidebar content not fit for mobile </p>
    </div>
    {% endif %>
    <div id="content">
      <article>
        {% if not request.mobile %}
        <aside>
          <p> aside content </p>
        </aside>
        {% endif %}
        <p> article content </p>
      </aricle>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```